# C# windows forms adding more files to playlist

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

When adding more files to my playlist, it throws an out of bounds exception. It doesn't throw the exception when you load files the first time around. I think the problem is because the playlist.SelectedIndex needs a value placed into it. Any ideas?

```cs
private void mediaPlayer_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if (e.newState == 1)
    {
        if (playlist.SelectedIndex < playlist.Items.Count)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {    
                if ((playlist.SelectedIndex + 1) < playlist.Items.Count)
                {
                     mediaPlayer.URL = paths[playlist.SelectedIndex];
                     playlist.SelectedIndex++;
                }
                else 
                {
                    mediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.stop();
                }
            }));
        }
    }
}

private void load_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        files = ofd.SafeFileNames;
        paths = ofd.FileNames;
    }

    for (int i =0; i< files.Length; i++)
    {
        playlist.Items.Add(files[i]);
    }

    playlist.SelectedIndex = 0;

}
```

Comment: Questions. 1.) At what line is the exception thrown exactly? 2.) Where is `playlist` instantiated? I think it has to do with instantiation of `playlist`. The first time it sets its size to the given files. When trying to add, it can't because its initial size is less.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: playlist is the name I gave the listbox instantiated in the designer.  exception throws on ' mediaPlayer.URL = paths[playlist.SelectedIndex];'

Comment: ps i get that arrays do not grow. the playlist.items is a list, not an array

Comment: There is code missing that gets the player activated.  So non-zero odds that SelectedIndex can be -1.  Note how the event handler has an off-by-one bug, it selects the URL that should have just finished playing.

Comment: Ah I found the answer. yes- listbox is a list. however the media player also needs the url to locate the file. The code I copied had an array of urls rather than a list or URLs.